How to smooth an arc
I am trying to plot an arc of circle using three points, and I got this image

But, as you see the arc is not really smooth, as you see the "zigzags" within the path. How can we remove them?
Here is part of my code:
library(ggplot2)
plot_arc <- function(C, r, P1, P2, P3) {
  t <- seq(atan2(P1[2] - C[2], P1[1] - C[1]), atan2(P2[2] - C[2], P2[1] - C[1]), length.out = 100000)
  x <- C[1] + r * cos(t)
  y <- C[2] + r * sin(t)
  data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
  
  p <- ggplot() +
    geom_path(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "blue", size=1.) +
    geom_point(aes(x = P1[1], y = P1[2]), color = "red", size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(x = P2[1], y = P2[2]), color = "green", size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(x = P3[1], y = P3[2]), color = "yellow", size = 3) +
    coord_fixed() 
 
  print(p) 
}

plot_arc(C_optimal, r_optimal, P1, P2, P3)


We do not have C_optimal, r_optimal, P1, P2, P3.

Try geom_smooth().

It looks zigzag on the screen due to the poor screen resolution. If you save the plot to a file, specifying a high dpi, then you'll get a much smoother arc. Similarly, if you save the plot to a pdf file.
plot_arc(C_optimal, r_optimal, P1, P2, P3)
ggsave("arc.jpeg", dpi=500)




I don't think you really need argument t, since your y is already a function of x, e.g., y <- arcfun(x)
Below is just an example with dummy input C and r
C <- c(1, 4)
r <- 2
arcfun <- function(x) C[2] - r * sqrt(1 - ((x - C[1]) / r)^2)
curve(arcfun, from = C[1], to = C[1] + r)
grid(10, 10)



Thanks, but same issue in your plot, but as the other answer says, it is question of resolution.

@Remember yes, that makes sense
